# What do we actually import from Express in a Node.js program

Tags: node.js, express

Usually when we import something in Node, we do something like:

```
const fs = require("fs");
... //use fs's methods for file system stuff
```

However, when we use express, we are doing:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get( .... )
```

What's the difference with the imports? why do we call `express()` like a function (I'm assuming it imports some function, and if it does, what does the function do)? In case it won't be explained by my previous questions, why don't we call function of the `express` object we imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export` of the `express` package is a function named `createApplication` (see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L28)). Calling this function produces an object. I believe it is done this way so that the `mixin`s are produced appropriately at run-time.

Also, keep in mind that in JavaScript, there are *no types*. Nothing is strictly an object. This function, for instance, has function members.

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;
exports.query = require('./middleware/query');  // Assigning a member function to the `createApplication` function.
```

Because of this, you can call `express()`, but also call `express.query('whatever')`. JavaScript is pretty nonsense if you try to interpret it as a well-defined object-oriented language.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes an incorrect assumption, you say

> why don't we call function of the `express` object

but `require("express")` returns a `Function`.

It's a difference in what is exported.  One exports an Object with properties attached to it while the other exports a Function.

Express does the latter.  See [express source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/express.js#L28):

```js
exports = module.exports = createApplication;

function createApplication() {...};
```

While node does the former, [node fs source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9987f1abb92461af5b2da61befe7ce0c1ab19503/lib/fs.js#L1796):

```js
module.exports = fs = {...};
```